# Highlight 'show more' comments

Tags: feature-request

When clicking "show more comments" the 'hidden' comments are now placed between the extant comments, and they are hard to find. Thus, we need to reread all the comments that we already read. Please consider somehow highlighting these 'added' comments. Perhaps a different background colour would help.

Thank you!